Upgrading Spring Boot from 2.7.14 to 3.2.4 giving 415 Unsupported Media Type
I have updated the Spring boot version from 2.7.14 to 3.2.4 in existing application. Rest everything remains same, but it is giving 415 unsupported media type.
I have spend days on this, but do not have any clue about it.
RestTemplate Configs -
@Configuartion
public class RestTemplateConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateFactory resTemplateFactory) {
        RestTemplate resTemplate = resTemplateFactory.restTemplate();
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setOutputStreaming(false);
        ClientRequestFactory factory = new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(requestFactory);
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);
        restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new AddResponseBodyWrapperInterceptor());
        return resTemplate;
    }
}

Calling class -
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ExternalApiService {
    private final RestTemplae restTemplate;
    
    public ResponseEntity<JsonNode> exchange(URI uri, HttpMethod method, HttpEntity<JsonNode> httpEntity) {
     try {
         ResponseEntity<JsonNode> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, method, httpEntity, JsonNode.class);
         return ResponseEntity.status(response.getStatusCode())
                  .headers(//code here)
                  .body(response.getBody());
     } catch (HttpStatusCodeException ex) {
        // exception handling
     }
  }
}

I have tried adding logging in the interceptor. Both before and after updating the spring boot version have same request headers and payload.
accept: "application/json, text/plain, application/xml, application/*+json, application/*+xml, */*",
accep-encoding: "gzip, x-gzip, deflat",
content-length: "0",
host: "localhost:9060",
connection: "keep-alive",
user-agent: "Apache-HttpClient/5.2.3 (Java/17.0.10)"

The exact same code work with Spring boot 2.7.14, but fails with 3.2.4.
Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Not sure if this will help, but if you are on Spring Boot 3.X you should give the RestClient a try. RestTemplate is not deprecated yet, but the new suggested clients in Spring are WebClient for asyncronous calls and RestClient for syncronous calls.
